# differential equation FP2

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am stuck on an FP2 edexcel differential equation.

Q5. $(1-x^2)\frac{dy}{dx} + xy = 5x$ 
The answer is $y=5 + c(1-x^2)^{1/2}$

[Question from fp2 edexcel book, pg 85](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oklW5.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things 
about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if 
you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in 
this and future posts and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers 
at the right level.
This site uses
[MathJax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: **Hint:** It is a Separable Equation - separate and integrate both sides. Other approaches possible, but that is easiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Moo pointed out, it is separable:

Divide through by $x$, rearrange and integrate to get (I'm doing it all pretty much in one step since it is not considered well-mannered to treat the derivative as fractions, even though it is basically how I carry out the operation, but don't tell anyone!):
$$\frac{(1-x^2)}{x}\frac{dy}{dx}=(5-y) \leftrightarrow \int \frac{1}{5-y}dy=\int \frac{x}{1-x^2}dx$$
which gives
$$-\ln(5-y)+c=-\frac{1}{2}\ln(1-x^2)$$

If you solve this for $y$, you get your result.

Answer (score 0):

$dy/dx +(x/(1-x^{2}))y=5x/1-x^{2}$

I.F =$(1-x^{2})^{-1/2}$
Just proceed on these lines